# How would i go about multiplying a number by a -1 in C?

Tags: c

i want to do this because i don't want to output a negative number. So i'd like to multiply it by -1 to make it positive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `if(num < 0) num *= -1;`?

Comment: How about using the function `abs(num)`

Answer (score 4):

There's a function called [`abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) that gives you that:

```
int x = -1;
int y = abs(x);
```

It effectively gives you the number without the sign, or the ["absolute value"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).